# Extend vi mode to irb, postgres etc in zsh

Tags: command-line, zsh, line-editor

I am using oh-my-zsh's `vi-mode` plugin. Its working awesomely for regular terminal usage.

How to extend this `vi-mode` to psql, irb etc?

In bash I used to do this by adding commands in `.inputrc`

I am using mac os sierra

Answer (score 3):

Its the `zsh` shell which uses `zle` instead of `readline`

Rest of the terminal apps still use `readline` even if they are invoked via `zsh`

Hence `.inputrc` works here for all the apps